# How do I show that this expression is greater than $0$?

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to show an expression is greater than $0$. The expression is $\frac{1}{n+1}+\log(\frac{n+1}{n+2})$. I can't really get anywhere with this, and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is $x-\log(1+x)$ for $x=\frac1{n+1}$ (*right?*). Consider the function $u$ defined on $x\geqslant0$ by $u(x)=x-\log(1+x)$, then $u(0)=0$ and, for every $x\geqslant0$, $u'(x)=1-\frac1{1+x}=\frac{x}{1+x}\geqslant0$, in particular $____$ for every $x\geqslant0$.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why you need to continue after you have shown that $\frac{x}{1+x}\geq0$.

Comment: "I don't understand" meaning "I find the last step obvious"? If so, things are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging we have to show that $\log(\frac{n+2}{n+1}) < \frac{1}{n+1} $ , but $$\log(\frac{n+2}{n+1}) = \log(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})= \int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}} \frac{1}{x} dx < \int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}} dx = \frac{1}{n+1} $$

and so we are done